# Ionic 2: Treating my mac like an Android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing an app using Ionic 2 and as you know, there is different styling for ios and android and most class names either get `-ios` or `-md` appended to them depending on the OS.

For some reason while developing on my mac, everything gets the `-md` designation and I was wondering:

**Is there a place to override this to state I want ios designations?**

Comment: _everything gets the -md designation_ what command do you use for running in mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Developer tips](https://ionicframework.com/docs//resources/developer-tips/#changing-the-platform) to how to change the platform. From your question, I assume you want to see how your app looks like when running it on an *ios* device (instead of settings the configuration to only use ios platform styles also for android)

So, in order to see how your app looks like in android, you can add `?ionicplatform=android` to the url, like this:

```
http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=android
```

You can do the same for ios, by adding `?ionicplatform=ios`:

```
http://localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=ios
```

You can achieve the same by specifying the platform in the `serve` command:
`ionic serve -t ios` or `ionic serve -t android`

---

You can also change *how the browser sees which platform and device you are on*, by changing the user-agent. To do this, open up Chrome DevTools, and toggle device mode on with Ctrl + Shift + M (Cmd + Shift + M on Mac).

[image]

After selecting an ios or android device, refresh the page and you should look the ios/android version of your app.